# How to get data from a form to jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to get a value inputted through a form and then back into my jinja template. Which I know doesn't make sense so I guess I am asking how do I go about doing what I want?. Here is what I have:

Python

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'] )
    def test():
    posts = db.posts
    facultyId = request.form.get("facultyId","");
    print "facultyId: ",facultyId
    return render_template('form.html',posts=posts,Id=facultyId)
```

form.html

```
<form method='post'>
        <table width="80%" border="5" align="center" bgcolor="white">       
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan= "4">
                            Faculty Identification Number: 
                            <input type="text" id="facultyId" name="facultyId" value=""/>

                    </th>       
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <th colspan= "4">
                        Number Of Evaluations: 
                            {% if posts.find({"Applicants.appId" : Id},{'Applicants.Evaluators':{'$exists': True }}).count() == 0 %}
                                {{posts.find({"Applicants.appId" : Id},{'Applicants.Evaluators':{'$exists': True }}).count() }}
                            {% else %}
                                {% for post in posts.find({"Applicants.appId" : Id}, { "Applicants.$.Evaluators" : 1 }) %}
                                    {{post["Applicants"][0]["Evaluators"]|length}}
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                    </th>
                    </tr>
                    <th colspan= "4"><button type="submit" >Submit</button></th>

                </tbody>
            </table>
</form>
```

I want to be able to submit a facultyId though a form and have it go into my jinja and run my mongodb find query. It works if I hard code the value in so if I did Id=100 in my python it works but if I do it though the forums it doesn't and the facultyId value is getting inputted because it does prints out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you do not parse `facultyId` as an integer. It works if you hardcode `100`, because it is an integer, but what you assign out of `request.form` is a string `"100"`.

After

```
facultyId = request.form.get("facultyId","")
```

add

```
facultyId = int(facultyId) if facultyId else None
```

Comment: Yup that was the problem thanks! I really need to stop trying to code at 4am.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set action controller as follows

```
<form method='post' action='/test'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put it in braces. Like this:

```
<form method='post'>
        <table width="80%" border="5" align="center" bgcolor="white">       
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan= "4">
                            Faculty Identification Number: 
                            <input type="text" id="facultyId" name="facultyId" value=""/>

                    </th>       
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <th colspan= "4">
                        Number Of Evaluations: 
                            {% if posts.find({"Applicants.appId" : {{Id}}},{'Applicants.Evaluators':{'$exists': True }}).count() == 0 %}
                                {{posts.find({"Applicants.appId" : {{Id}}},{'Applicants.Evaluators':{'$exists': True }}).count() }}
                            {% else %}
                                {% for post in posts.find({"Applicants.appId" : {{Id}}}, { "Applicants.$.Evaluators" : 1 }) %}
                                    {{post["Applicants"][0]["Evaluators"]|length}}
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                    </th>
                    </tr>
                    <th colspan= "4"><button type="submit" >Submit</button></th>

                </tbody>
            </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest to put your posts.find logic into your route function, then pass it's results to your form in the posts variable.